# CORS issue with localhost despite proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have created a REST API for the backend of this project and am using React to make the client side of the app. I have been getting this error when I am trying to login to my app.

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://studioghiblidb.herokuapp.com/login' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

I was advised to include the local host as a proxy which I did in my client side package.json like this

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "process": "^0.11.10"
  },
  "proxy" : "http://localhost:1234/"
```

On the server side I was instructed to use this code to keep from cross site forgery issues. I have included the essentials as accepted origins

```
const cors = require('cors');

 let allowedOrigins = [
'http://localhost:8080', 
'http://testsite.com',
'http://localhost',
'http://localhost:1234',
'https://studioghiblidb.herokuapp.com/'
];

app.use(cors({
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if(!origin) return callback(null, true);
    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1){
       let message = 'The CORS policy for this application does not allow found on the list of allowed origin' + origin;
       return callback(new Error(message), false);
  }
  return callback(null, true);
}
}));
```

I am at a complete loss as to what is causing the CORS error to keep from giving a JWT token and logging in. I have tested in Postman and the users are there and working

Comment: First and foremost, inspect the response in your network tab. What is the request type? status code? Headers? etc. If you aren't getting the response you expected, you should see what response you actually received so that you know where to begin looking.

Comment: I am honestly not sure what I am looking for there, there are 2 login responses, the first is for the CORS error with a 400 error and a second one saying my user is not found but I think that is just because it is not properly connecting.

Answer (score -1):

In the request header add Allow-cross-origin: '*'. Also, enable cors from the backend.

**NOT RECOMMENDED FOR PRODUCTION** only for development purposes. Disable secure mode in chrome.

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```